# How to search for upcoming conferences that will be held in a specific subject

Tags: conference

What is the best way to search for conferences all over world? I need to participate in one in the near future.

Comment: depending on your field http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/ may be helpful

Comment: It would help to specify what field you are in.

Comment: Quantitative search: google "conference in X"; Qualitative search: check where the authors you appreciate present papers.

Comment: Why not try this website http://www.conferencealerts.com/ It is a website about conferences all over the world whatever the academic topic!

Comment: @JuandaCruz The web site you suggest has extremely poor coverage of computer science conferences.

Comment: I think this is a broad question (the answer varies for different fields) and also is a kind of shopping question, seeking for a list of websites (as can be seen in the existing answers).

Answer (score 4):

By doing reasonable googling. As you didn't state your topic let me make an example when [searching for conferences on magnetism](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&prmdo=1&q=registration+intitle%3Aconference+magnetism+|+magnetic+material+|+physics+inurl%3Aedu+|+inurl%3Auni+-filetype%3Apdf+-filetype%3Adoc+-filetype%3Appt+-filetype%3Aps+2014..2014&oq=registration+intitle%3Aconference+magnetism+|+magnetic+material+|+physics+inurl%3Aedu+|+inurl%3Auni+-filetype%3Apdf+-filetype%3Adoc+-filetype%3Appt+-filetype%3Aps+2014..2014). The operators I use should be self-explaining. Most conferences will be announced on websites of universities or mentioned, to exclude old ones search only within `2014..2014`, and so on...

See also my [other answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/455/213) which has some links how to use google properly

Answer (score 2):

For computer science conferences:

1. [WikiCFP](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/)
2. [EventSeer](http://eventseer.net/)
3. Springer [LNCS forthcoming proceedings](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/LNCS_Forthcoming_Proceedings.pdf):
4. ACM [calendar of events](http://www.acm.org/calendar-of-events)
5. IEEE [list of events](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/index.html)

Subject-specific mailing lists, such as:

1. [DBWorld](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/dbworld/)
2. [AISWorld](http://www.aisnet.org/AIS_Lists/publiclists.aspx)
3. [ACM SIG-IR list](http://www.sigir.org/sigirlist/)
4. [ECOOP info list](http://web.satd.uma.es/mailman/listinfo/ecoop-info)

Comment: This basically summarizes the near-duplicate https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40438/computer-science-central-source-for-cfps

Answer (score 1):

I have a very good experience with national and similar subject mailing lists, for instance French "Groupes de Recherche" such as http://www.gdr-im.fr/ intended for Theoretical Computer Science. There're dozens of them in France for instance.

Once you are a member of such group, you recieve quite a lot of mail (subject prefixed by `[gdr-im]`), most of it are information on interesteing seminars, job offers and conference CfP (for both local and international meetings). I have found being a member of this mailing list very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Nature's website has a [list](http://www.nature.com/natureevents/science/) of scientific conferences and events (324 events are listed in September 2014), but may be biased towards certain fields. I think I saw similar lists in other journals as well.

Answer (score 1):

I worked as an administrator for the 21st McGill International Entrepreneurship conference and we listed our conference on a conference announcement directory called PaperCrowd.

It attracted several delegates from around the world. I found out it was in the same city I lived in and I applied for a job there and got it! I am now the proud community manager of PaperCrowd. We are working hard to improve the services for researchers worldwide.

You should try PaperCrowd - a global directory of academic research conferences. You can search by topics, geography and keywords for research conferences you are interested in such as law, legal etc.

Organizers add their events in a couple of minutes and it’s free. It’s restricted to academic research conferences.

It feels good working for a company that I have seen myself was effective.

https://www.papercrowd.com/

Comment: If you are affiliated with PaperCrowd, [as you state here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/98309/20411), you need to disclose your affiliation in every answer where you promote this service. See also [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).