# Is there a unified platform that lists conference/journal deadlines?

Tags: journals, conference, deadlines, website

Is there any unified platform that would list the deadlines (especially the submission deadlines) for conferences/journals? Ideally I would like to select a few conferences/journals I am interested in publishing to, and the website would give me the list of upcoming deadlines.

Right now I have to check out each individual conference/journal website, which is pretty tedious and error-prone (all the more so as it is pretty common for deadline to be extended).

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science > machine learning, and English-speaking venues.

Comment: http://www.confsearch.org/

Comment: Wikicfp has a nice timeline view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search for upcoming conferences that will be held in a specific subject](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27002/how-to-search-for-upcoming-conferences-that-will-be-held-in-a-specific-subject)

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thanks but I think that's two different questions: I'm just interested in deadlines and I am looking for a way to list deadlines for a chosen set of conferences (just like in Wikicfp), which can have different topics.

Comment: Okay, I agree and I retracted my close vote.  But you will need to tell the site which conferences you are interested in.  How can that be any faster than just checking the deadlines yourself?

Comment: *I am looking for a way to list deadlines for a chosen set of conferences (just like in Wikicfp)* - what's wrong with wikicfp then?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I am interested in 10 conferences/journals. Each year I have to check their websites, it's a bit tedious, all the more so as you never know when the deadlines are published and when they change, which mean I need to check all websites at least a few times, and make my own calendar.

Comment: @ff524 Nothing, your comment was actually a great answer. I knew wikicfp but I missed the timeline view feature.

Comment: What are journal deadlines? Every journal I know has continuous submission except for special issues which are usually invited anyways.

Comment: "confsearch.org" – Now dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WikiCFP](http://wikicfp.com/cfp/home) offers this. To use this feature, you are required to register and sign in to your account.

Once you are logged in, find the Calls for Papers (CFPs) you are interested in and choose "Add to my list". (You can add multiple CFPs at a time if they appear in the same search results or "recent CFPs" list).

Then, from the sidebar, choose "My list" or "Timeline" to see all the deadlines for the conferences you have selected in your preferred format. Timeline view is pretty nice; it shows you the registration, submission, notification, and camera-ready deadlines, as well as the dates of the actual conference. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Wikicfp timeline view]

However, WifiCFP relies on user-submitted content (for both original CFP submissions, and updates e.g., for deadline extensions). So the usefulness of this for you will depend on how active people in your field are on WikiCFP.

Comment: I've found WikiCFP to be worse than useless in the past. It often lists incorrect dates, which is worse than listing nothing. So be wary.

Comment: @Thomas It does not list incorrect dates. WikiCfp is none other than its users. The date change might occur because the user didn't edit the deadline (dates) of the conference. So, blaming the website as a whole is not a good idea, I guess.

Comment: Sure. I think they are trying to do a good thing. I just think people should be warned that the data is not always reliable, so yo should confirm with an official source.

Answer (score 5):

http://allconferencecfpalerts.com/ is a unified platform that lists conference / journal deadlines.

It also provides Open Access Research Sharing System - Share URL

Share-url link in the allconferencecfpalerts.com site is mainly built for researchers to share their academic information category wise. It is an open access platform to help researchers get more visibility and citations. This page is user-friendly so that authors can share information easily.

Authors who wish to post their Research information should register by creating Login id password. Login or registration is not required to view, search and download articles from the portal. All Share URL posts are categorized based on research area. User can search by title of the paper or author's name.