# Computer science central source for CFPs

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, paper-submission

In the field of computer science, is there somewhere out there a central database containing a complete list (or at least most of the important one) of conferences and Call For Papers (CFP) to browse and subscribe to?

I found the following pages ([source](http://www.eur.nl/researchmatters/getting_published_and_measuring_impact/conferences/finding/)):

- [Allconferences.com](http://www.allconferences.com/) (conferences, trade shows and conventions)
- [Confabb.com](http://www.confabb.com/) (mostly trade fairs, but some academic conferences)
- [Conference Alerts.com](http://www.conferencealerts.com/) (academic conferences worldwide)
- [conference-service.com](http://conference-service.com) (mathematics, physics, nuclear applications, chemistry, earth sciences, computer science)
- [Eventseer.net](http://eventseer.net/) (computer science and linguistics)
- [PapersInvited.com](http://www.papersinvited.com/) (academic conferences worldwide)*
- [WikiCFP](http://www.wikicfp.com/) (A wiki site to organize and share CFP)
- [Academic Conferences Publishing House](http://www.ourglocal.com/) (CFP of Worldwide Academic Conference, meetings, symposia, workshops, Special Issues of
  International Journal)

Are there better ones?

---

EDIT:

Thanks for your answers. Here is the extended list based on your answers:

- [DBWorld](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/dbworld/)
- [SEWorld](http://www.sigsoft.org/seworld/) (Software Enineering Mailing List)
- [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/index.html) Conferences & Events

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other sites for multi-disciplinary CfP's

- [**PaperCrowd***](https://www.papercrowd.com/?utm_source=academicstackexchange)
- [Research Bible](http://www.researchbib.com/)
- [H-Net](http://h-net.org/announce/submit1.cgi)
- [Conferize](http://conferize.com)
- [Conference Submit](http://conferencesubmit.com)
- [OurGlocal](http://ourglocal.com)
- [BrownWalker](http://brownwalker.com/conferences/index.php)
- [All Conference Alert](http://allconferencealert.com)
- [List of conference.org](http://listofconference.org)
- [All Conference Alerts](http://allconferencealerts.com)
- [Conferensum](http://www.conferensum.com)

*Disclosure: I'm a co-founder at Ex Ordo and we built PaperCrowd as our contribution to the research community. It's restriced to academic research conferences and is free.