# Academic Event corpora

Tags: conference

For my research I need to find academic event corpora. Unfortunately the question [Computer science central source for CFPs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40438/computer-science-central-source-for-cfps) was closed as a "Shopping list question". In my case I am interested in datasets that link

- Call for Papers
- Conference Home Page
- Papers published for a conference e.g. via proceedings

So far I found (on top of the list in the other question):

- http://www.openresearch.org
- http://portal.confref.org/
- https://scholia.toolforge.org/ (based on Wikidata)

Comment: I am not asking to make a choice ... i need a list for my research. I am not interested in the rating in the options - i just want to know which options are out there. How could i rephrase the question to get the wanted scientific result?

Comment: What is your end goal?