# Is there a general way to find or get notified of relevant conferences and meetings in your field?

Tags: publications, conference

Here's the problem: I don't know what are the relevant conferences and meetings for me to potentially attend/present in. Every conference I've been so far has been passed down to me by a much older professor who knows it by experience.

I feel like this is an important topic, and yet all the tools I tried to use to find conferences (such as [allconferences](http://www.allconferences.com/) and [conferecealerts](https://conferencealerts.com/)) fail to find me relevant things.

Is there a method to reliably find relevant for you conferences worldwide?
Ideally it would be good to get notified when a new relevant conference is announced.

I know there are some websites (such as [arxiv-sanity](http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/) and [google Scholar](http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/)) that suggest papers for you to read based on previously loaded papers, so I wouldn't be surprised if there was some similar tool where you put some conferences with a few keywords and it spits out suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 5):

Many professional societies publish lists of upcoming conferences in their magazines and/or journals, and send monthly emails with information that usually includes calls for papers for future conferences. I assume one would be interested only in conferences in one's field. I would expect that one would know about the professional societies in one's field and how to receive notifications, although in many if not most cases such notifications go only to the society members.

Moreover, other conferences in one's field can be identified in Google Scholar by where the relevant papers have been published. Then the most recent (at least) web site for such conferences can be found with Google. The date and venue for the next conference in that series is sometimes posted on that web site.

Answer (score -1):

I worked as an administrator for the 21st McGill International Entrepreneurship conference and we listed our conference on a conference announcement directory called PaperCrowd.

It attracted several delegates from around the world. I found out it was in the same city I lived in and I applied for a job there and got it! I am now the proud community manager of PaperCrowd. We are working hard to improve the services for researchers worldwide.

You should try PaperCrowd - a global directory of academic research conferences. You can search by topics, geography and keywords for research conferences you are interested in such as law, legal etc.

Organizers add their events in a couple of minutes and it’s free. It’s restricted to academic research conferences.

It feels good working for a company that I have seen myself was effective.

Comment: Is the quality of the conferences vetted (by peers or otherwise) or do you include all kinds of fake and predatory conferences?

Comment: Predatory conferences are something we have encountered and we are working against. We plan to add in a web-page with the conferences we have marked as questionable or suspect. Currently, I would recommend to cross reference the conference organizer and conference name with Beall's list of predatory conferences and his list of predatory publishers. As seen with what happened to Jeffrey Beall there is a very fine line legally with how you approach questionable conferences.

Answer (score -1):

I use [CFP Wiki](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/). You can browse conferences by category and set up RSS alerts for each one, so you can get updates on new conferences or editions.

Comment: Careful with CFP wiki, though. Their database includes some legitimate conferences, but in my field, 90% of the listed venues are predatory/fake.