# Tips on finding research groups that focus on credit scoring based on alternative data

Tags: publications, research-process, networking, research-group

Despite conducting a thorough Google search implementing all the tips provided in answers to this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-do-i-find-research-groups-that-do-work-in-field-x), I still haven't managed to find a single active research group (at a university, or a public research institute) that focuses on **credit scoring based on alternative data**. (By alternative data I mostly refer to mobile phone data, psychometrics-related data, social network data, digital footprint data etc - virtually anything besides traditional credit history data provided by credit bureaus).

I did manage to find the famous [Entrepreneurial Finance lab](https://innovationlabs.harvard.edu/ventures/venture-teams/) at Harvard University, however, they don't seem to be active or publishing anymore since they started an extremely [successful spin-off company](https://include1billion.com/).

There seem to be many startups focusing on alternative data based credit scoring but their technology is of course proprietary and I can't find any relevant papers.

So what I'm looking for is a) tips on how to find relevant research groups given the circumstances outlined above or* b) a name or even better, a list of names of research groups/labs focusing on alternative data based credit scoring. (I'm doing some background reading before officially starting my PhD studies)

- inclusive OR

**EDIT:** After taking into account Flyto's comment I've changed the question title in order to adhere to the policy.

Comment: Ask your supervisor, ask the Entrepreneurial Finance lab, ask LenddoEFL.

Comment: Perhaps they don't want to be found...

Comment: Hi BGa, welcome to Stackexchange. Your question (b) is a "shopping question", i.e. asking for recommendations for specific subject-based organisations, which tends to be discouraged around here (partly because the chance of somebody here knowing exactly the right specialism are rather small). Your question (a) is however a good one, so I recommend editing your title to reflect that aspect.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest looking also at the legal and ethical ramifications of these questions. It might explain why there's little research on the topic.

Comment: Flyto, thank you for the feedback - I've edited the question title.

Comment: I was about to close your question before reading the comments. The question “how do I find research groups doing research on a particular topic?” Is okay because the answers would outline a general approach; “how do I find research groups working on X?” is not, because it’s unlikely to help future visitors.